# OnCompleted y Timer con Angular2

Tags: angular

Tengo un formulario de insertar productos, **el botón enviar debe quedar desactivado** mientras el servidor realiza la petición que puede ser que sea cierta o falsa.

Entonces sea cierto o falso, se mostrará un alert confirmando o no. (Con Clarity)

Cuando tienes un alert te sale una 'x' para cerrar el alert, el problema es que si cierras el alert, nunca más se muestra ningún alert.
Entonces quité la posibilidad al usuario de quitarlos usando la 'x'. Entonces necesito un Timer para que vaya **cerrando los alerts.**

```
 insert(formModifyConfig: NgForm) {

        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/insert';


        this.service.insert(url , this.product).subscribe(param => {

            let params = JSON.parse(param);
            this.myMessage.success = params.success;
            this.myMessage.message =  params.message;

            if ( this.myMessage.success) {
                this.openModalUpdate = false;
                this.confirmedServer = true;
            } else {
                this.errorServer = true;
            }

        },  error => {
            this.errorServer = true;
            this.myMessage.message = "Error Server";
        });
   }
```

Aquí probé con :

Cuando se le da al botón , desactivarlo

```
  formModifyConfig.status = false; --> Second error.
  formModifyConfig.form.invalid = true;  --> Second error.
  formModifyConfig.form.invalid() etc
```

Pero no funciona porque dice que es una constante y no se le pueda cambiar el valor.

Después cuando la petición se ha resuelto volver a ponerlo.

```
      error => {
                this.errorServer = true;
                this.myMessage.message = "Error Server";
        },OnCompleted => {
            formModifyConfig.enable;
        });
```

HTML

```
        <h3 class="modal-title">Insert{{ staticParamName }}</h3>

        <div class="modal-body">

                <clr-alert  [clrAlertClosable]="false" [clrAlertType]="'alert-danger'" *ngIf="errorServer">
                        <clr-alert-item>
                            <span class="alert-text">
                               {{ this.myMessage.message }}
                            </span>
                        </clr-alert-item>
                     </clr-alert>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <label for="nameParameter">Name: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" id="nameParameter" name="nameParameter" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="insert.parameter" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <label for="description">Description: </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" id="description" name="description" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="insert.description">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="insertConfig.form.invalid">Insert</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="openModalUpdate = false">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </clr-modal>
</form>
```

Finalmente para poder cerrar los mensajes con tiempo he mirado  https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/alerts

Y no tienen el temporizador, tienen para deshabilitar la 'x'

Espero que haya quedado claro los 2 problemas que tengo, si necesitan más explicación o mejor, no duden en pedirla.Gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar la función `setTimeout`

Comment: lo he puesto en el ngOnInit y solo se ejecuta 1 vez

Comment: Tienes que usar setTimeout cada vez que creas el alert, si quieres que se cierre